# Linear Operator with finite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm involved with this exercise. I would greatly appreciate your help

> Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over a field $F$. Let $T: V
> \rightarrow V$ a linear transformation whose image and kernel are the
>   same subspace of $V$. proves that $n$ is even

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $T:V\rightarrow W$ then $\text{dim}(V)=\text{dim}(K)+\text{dim}(T(V))$, where $K$ is the kernel of $T$.  In your case those two terms on the right hand side are equal.  So the LHS must be divisible by two.

Answer (score 0):

Linear transformation $ T $ induces a isomorphism

$V/Ker(T) \cong Im(T)$

Hence $dim(V/Ker(T)) = dim(Im(T))$

$dim(V/Ker(T)) = dim(V)-dim(Ker(T))$ and  $dim(Ker(T)) = dim(Im(T))$

Conclude that  $dim(V) = 2dim(Im(T))$ which means $n$ is even.

$ $

And in the question : "Kernel and image  are same ", may be a typo .

"Kernel and image are isomorphic" is a sufficient hypothesis.

(If you say kernel=image , that means $V = {0} \Rightarrow n =0$)